# how can i draw a text with a 9 patch drawable

Tags: java, android, drawable, nine-patch

I already know how to draw text on a regular drawable:

```
 public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    paint.setTextSize(20); 

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}
```

or even like this :

```
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(tile_types[tileType]);
// Store our image size as a constant
final int IMAGE_WIDTH = image.getIntrinsicWidth();
final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = image.getIntrinsicHeight();

// You can also use Config.ARGB_4444 to conserve memory or ARGB_565 if 
// you don't have any transparency.
Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(IMAGE_WIDTH, 
                                      IMAGE_HEIGHT, 
                                      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
// Create a canvas, that will draw on to canvasBitmap. canvasBitmap is
// currently blank.
Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
// Set up the paint for use with our Canvas
Paint imagePaint = new Paint();
imagePaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
imagePaint.setTextSize(16f);

// Draw the image to our canvas
image.draw(imageCanvas);
// Draw the text on top of our image
imageCanvas.drawText("Sample Text", 
                     IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, 
                     IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2, 
                     imagePaint);
// This is the final image that you can use 
BitmapDrawable finalImage = new BitmapDrawable(canvasBitmap);
```

, but how can i use a 9-patch drawable that will be able to take up the size of the text i enter.

Comment: can't you put the 9patch as background for a  TextView?

Comment: What i'm trying to do it use it as an overlayitem in a mapview, so i need to pass a drawable

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? I am trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: Still nothing, i have to use normal drawable.